# Firebase Cloud Messaging works only after first start of the app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to the users using my app. 
But the notifications only arrive after the user opened the app the first time. 
Can somebody help me?
Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [Firebase FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) properly? The FCM token is triggered when FCM token is not created yet in users phone. If existed, the push notification will not be a problem if the app is not open. You can called *onTokenRefresh()* to init the FCM token.